# firebase domain name requirement

Tags: android, firebase, dns, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a mobile app. However, I'm working on the part where users can reset their password. I realize that I may need a domain name in order to complete this step. Why is that the case? Do I have to code a web version of my app as well?

Answer (score 1):

When Firebase send the user a password reset email, that email contains a link to a web page where they can reset their password. By default this web page will be on `<yourprojectname>.firebaseapp.com`, but you may want to customize that in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails).

The page itself is auto-generated through, so you won't need to build or deploy a web site for this.

Comment: I'm on that page now where I can customize the web page which i did iput htttps:aloo.com. But when I click that link fom my email it tells me the page has been suspeneded. I'm gussing I need to do an actual domian becuase it was trying to go go to some sort of website

Comment: If you enter a custom domain, it is important that you actually own that domain and have it registered correctly with Firebase. Otherwise Firebase won't be able to host its auto-generated page that is in the email on the domain.

Comment: ok thank you for that information.